# MP4 and M4V files with DLNA

Tags: video

While attempting serve a collection of purchased MP4 and M4V content through DLNA with 13.04, a systemic problem seems to be present. The server is Ubuntu 13.04. The client is a Blue-Ray player client. This is across a 1G line. When opening content with any Ubuntu supported DLNA software, (PMS, Rygel,ushare, etc) the video will load an a message will pop on the client saying, "The connection failed, please check your network settings." The model of Blue-Ray player maybe at fault. The question is: Is this becoming a problem with DLNA?

Users experiencing this problem may post similar experiences.

Comment: Does the Blueray player support this file format? Are the files DRM protected?

Comment: After using LINN on the iPAD successfully play DLNA MP4 and M4V material across the DMP-BDT-320 through my Onkyo RC450 into my LG TV, there is not a problem with any of these DLNA servers. The issue is the client on the Panasonic. This can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Not all clients on proprietary hardware claiming to be DLNA compliant are created equal. The problem was with the DLNA browser embedded in the Panasonic DMP-BDT-320. With no updates with BIOS, an alternate player can be used. LINN for the iPAD is good tool to wirelessly push content from the Ubuntu DLNA server onto the DMP-BDT-320 player to play. Very cool.